# Function in a for loop not randomizing

Tags: java

I have this function run 10 times in a for loop, its supposed to randomize and give random ores, but right now the script gives 10 copper ore

```
    public void mineOre() {

        int ore = (int) Math.random() * 10 + 1;

        if(ore ==1) {                       
            inventory.addInventory("Copper Ore");
        } else if(ore ==2) {                        
            inventory.addInventory("Iron Ore");
        } else if(ore ==3) {                        
            inventory.addInventory("Steel Ore");
        }else if(ore ==4) {                     
            inventory.addInventory("Gold Ore");
        }else if(ore ==5) {                     
            inventory.addInventory("Iron Ore");
        } else if(ore > 6) {                        

        }
    }
```

I have that function running on this

```
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                mineOre();
            }
```

How can I fix mineOre so that it randomizes? Right now it feels like math.random() runs once and then it uses that number 10 times

I also tried

```
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                int ore = (int) Math.random() * 10 + 1;
                if(ore ==1) {                       
                    inventory.addInventory("Copper Ore");
                } else if(ore ==2) {                        
                    inventory.addInventory("Iron Ore");
                } else if(ore ==3) {                        
                    inventory.addInventory("Steel Ore");
                }else if(ore ==4) {                     
                    inventory.addInventory("Gold Ore");
                }else if(ore ==5) {                     
                    inventory.addInventory("Iron Ore");
                } else if(ore > 6) {                        

                }
            }
```

It still gives 10 copper ore

Comment: `int ore = (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1;`

Comment: You should also consider using `Random` class instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
    int ore = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
```

The cast to int binds more tightly than the multiplication.

It would be even better to use the `nextInt` method from the [`java.util.Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class: it is more efficient and guarantees a uniform distribution. The multiply-and-cast method may have a slight bias.

```
private Random myRandom = new Random();
public void mineOre() {

    int ore = myRandom.nextInt(10)+1

    if(ore ==1) {                       
    ....
}
```

Comment: No need to wrap `+1` in the parenthesis.

Comment: +1 Although preferably a `Random` object would be used instead.